# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\main.php on line 15

Tags: php

I have Problem with my recursion function. I want to wait until text file input change then redirect to new page.

15 line is

```
$readedData = fread($myfile,filesize("my1.txt"));
```

this is my function

```
first();

function first() {
    $myfile = fopen("my1.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $number = fread($myfile,filesize("my1.txt"));

    fclose($myfile);
    recursion($number);
}

function recursion($number2) { 
    $myfile = fopen("my1.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $readedData = fread($myfile,filesize("my1.txt"));

    echo ($readedData ); 

    fclose($myfile);
    if($number2 != $readedData){
        return (recursion($readedData));
    }
    else if($number2 == $readedData){
        return(first());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there somewhere in the script likely to be using 1.3 GB?  It does not look like it is here.

Comment: it's 134 MB not 1.3GB

Comment: Check your php.ini setting.

Comment: thanks Ben, looks much better (formatting).  the php.ini setting is most likely the default 128MB (134m), the 1.3GB was a mis-parse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you do, your recursion is not bounded, it keeps calling deeper and deeper.  Waiting for a condition is usually handled with a conditional loop, not self-recursion.

first() always calls recursion()

recursion() calls itself, or calls first().  Which always calls recursion().

You see the problem -- these calls never end, they always call recursion().  Each call allocates stack space to be able to run, until the maximum configured limit is hit (130MB by default, which is what your error reported too)

Edit: php has no setInterval() like javascript, and in php recursive calls are truly recursive, they do not just queue a continuable.  To wait until the file changes in a loop you can do something like:

```
function waitAndRedirect( $filename ) {
    waitForchange(file_get_contents($filename));
    handleRedirect();
}

function waitForChange( $oldData ) {
    while (true) {
        $currentData = file_get_contents($filename);
        if ($currentData !== $oldData) return;
        else usleep(200);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to wait until text file change. this can do it but above error come out. is there any keyword like `setintervel` in java script ?

Comment: see edit above.  in php one has to program using blocking calls, and recursion always makes immediate calls, not like in javascript

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) function instead of `fread`, `echo`, `fclose`.

As for the actual recursion logic, it seems like you're going through an infinite loop. `first()` calls `recursion()` which calls `first()` again. So it loops forever until you hit the memory limit.

Try replacing `return(first());` with `return();`

Comment: you mean get_file_contents().  the echo in the code above has got to be a debugging tracer; the user would not want unending copies of the file to flood their browser

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'wait until text file input change'? Who is changing the input file?

In your code, you haven't set any stop condition.

`first()` will call `recursion()` in any circumstance and `recursion()` will either call `recursion()` or `first()`. Those two functions never get to stop once you call any one of them. And inside each function, you have to allocate `$readedData`, `$number`, `$number2`, but nothing gets deallocated.
That's why your memory will be exhausted.

Please define 'wait until text file input change' and provide the content of the input file so we may discuss further or help to improve the code.